# appcelerator - provisioning file is invalid or is the wrong type

Tags: appcelerator

Developing a camera based app in Appcelerator and want to test/debug. I have set up the necessary certificates in apple dev centre. When I select 'run as' and select my iPhone I progress through the setup  (General->Certificates->Provisioning) and when I choose the apple provisioning file at step 3 I get "Specified provisioning file is invalid or is the wrong type". Any ideas?

Otherwise, are there alternatives to test the photo access during development?

Thank you.

Comment: Launch XCode and refresh the list of provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Just to test the code of camera app - try these options

1. Replace the APP ID in tiapp.xml of your camera app with any other app which can be run on your device and set the certificates and profiles of camera app with the new app ones.
2. Or put the camera code you want to test in some other running app on your device. (no need to change the certificates and profiles in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **alternatives to test the photo access during development**, if you only need to test the access, you may test on photo album instead using simulator.

Camera & album access are very similar: **Ti.Media.showCamera** vs **Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery**